# A simple For loop to print partial sums of infinite sequence gives error: replacement has length zero

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, infinite-sequence

A simple problem in R using the For loop to compute partial sums of an infinite sequence is running into an error.

```
t <- 2:20
a <- numeric(20)  # first define the vector and its size
b <- numeric(20)

a[1]=1
b[1]=1 

for (t in seq_along(t)){  
       a[t] = ((-1)^(t-1))/(t) # some formula
       b[t] = b[t-1]+a[t]        
}
b
```

> Error in b[t] <- b[t - 1] + a[t] : replacement has length zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great deal of power of R comes from vectorization. Here there is no need of `for` loops. You can apply your formula directly on `t` (the vector of input values). Then notice that `b` is the cumulative sum of `a`.

Just try:

```
t <- 1:20
a <- ((-1)^(t-1))/(t)
b <- cumsum(a)
```

Comment: `a <- c(1, -1)/(1:20); b <- cumsum(a)`

Answer (score 1):

Two changes :-

1) Use different variable in `for` loop

2) Don't use `seq_along` since `t` has already the index on which you want to iterate

```
for (i in t){  
  a[i] = ((-1)^(i-1))/(i) # some formula
  b[i] = b[i-1]+a[i]        
}
```

Also `t` is not a good variable name since it is a function in R